# Node.js - Stripe issued card balance

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the total balance of the issued card. Any idea how can i do that. Didn't find any resource in the doc https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/cards that says how can i get total balance of issued card. 
Also in this doc
https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/funding/balance

Is it possible or i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The "total balance" for any card is the balance in the issuers account that is available to all issued cards.

You can add spending limits for specific cards so that there is a limit. You can do this in the dashboard or with the authorization webhook event.